# Get id value from url with Javascript

Tags: javascript

question is simple but still complicated for me

i want to get id value from a url which is 12345 by the way and want to insert it in below iframe as you can see

www.domain.com/page.php?id=12345

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="640" height="432" src="www.domain2.com/embed/video/12345"></iframe>
```

through php its so simple, but how we can do this with java script
i saw many answers but on my page they did not work still i need help how we can do this

Comment: What have you tried but it didn't work, please post your code

Comment: actually i saw many answered when i searched it on google but i dont know how i can use them on my page i want a full page  where it should work

Comment: You need to understand that philosophy of developing a web app with Java is entirely different from PHP, this is probably a http://xyproblem.info/ , so you need to learn Java and some framework like spring boot and then you'll have your anwser

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = "www.domain.com/page.php?id=12345";

// approach 1:  using `URLSearchParams`
var id_value1 = new URLSearchParams(url.split("?")[1]).get("id");


// approach 2: using string `split` and array `filter` methods.
// this will work even url has more parameters
var id_value2 = url
  .split("?")[1]
  .split("&")
  .filter(param => param.includes("id="))[0]
  .split("=")[1];

// approach 3: if you know, url will only have `id` param, then simply
var id_value3 = url.split("id=")[1];

console.log({ id_value1, id_value2, id_value3 });
```